# RubyMine error: Unable to run gem 'rails'. Cannot find 'rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubymine

When I try to create Rails Application with RubyMine, it fails with message "Unable to run gem 'rails'. Cannot find 'rails'". Why? And how to solve it?

RubyMine's version is 4.0.2.

There's some information about my system:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]
$ gem -v
1.8.11
$ uname -a
Linux somehost 3.2.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Tue Mar 20 18:36:37 UTC 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux testing (wheezy)
$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
```

Here's output of gem list --local: http://pastebin.com/CymzGUpf

RubyMine see the same set of gems: http://ompldr.org/vZGM2eA

Other IDEs for Ruby and Ruby on Rails (Eclipse with plugin DLTK-Ruby, Netbeans) work fine.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: What is the location of the rails script? Is it executable? Most likely it's not in the same place where ruby is located, therefore RubyMine is not able to run it (check with `whereis rails`). You can also try RubyMine 4.0.3 RC from http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/RUBYDEV/RubyMine+EAP.

Comment: rails: /usr/local/bin/rails, ruby: /usr/bin/ruby

Comment: `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rails /usr/bin/rails`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This problem is caused by `ruby` and `rails` executable files being located in different directories, normally they should be in the same directory and RubyMine is looking for the `rails` script in the same location where the configured `ruby` interpreter binary is.

In this particular case the locations were as follows:

- `/usr/local/bin/rails`
- `/usr/bin/ruby`

One of the solutions is to create a symlink of the `rails` script in the `/usr/bin` directory:

`sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/rails /usr/bin/rails`