# Rubymine - Rails gem not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine

I installed Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3 going through this solution -  http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/. It's really amazing and effortless. There were no errors while I did this.

Now I try to create a Rails project in Rubymine 4 but there's an error: "Rails version - no Rails gem found".

Terminal shows me:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ rails -v
Rails 3.2.3
alex@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]
alex@ubuntu:~$
```

UPDATE

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2012-04-20 patchlevel 194) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
     - /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
alex@ubuntu:~$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.3)
actionpack (3.2.3)
activemodel (3.2.3)
activerecord (3.2.3)
activeresource (3.2.3)
activesupport (3.2.3)
arel (3.0.2)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.4)
erubis (2.7.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
json (1.7.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.3)
railties (3.2.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.12)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.3)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
alex@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [RubyMine error: Unable to run gem 'rails'. Cannot find 'rails'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105481/rubymine-error-unable-to-run-gem-rails-cannot-find-rails)

Comment: it's not a duplicate. I already saw it. There are no files located `/usr/local/bin/rails` or `/usr/bin/ruby` in my system.

Comment: Provide the output of `gem environment` and `gem list`. Did you configure the same Ruby interpreter location as you are using from the terminal? Do you have `ruby` and `rails` in the same directory (`whereis ruby`, `whereis rails`)?

Comment: @CrazyCoder, I don't know. How do I check it? But it's absolutely there are no files located `/usr/local/bin/rails` or `usr/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This may help for rubymine.

You need to add ruby sdks

In RubyMine from file -> settings -> ruby Sdk and Gems -> add sdk

You can add multiple ruby version sdks and its gems

You can edit project specific ruby setup after starting project from menu

run -> edit configuration -> ruby sdk (select specific rails environment)

```
$ which ruby  #to get current ruby path
```

Comment: Where do I find a Rails SDK? What's the path?

Comment: type  'which ruby " in console ,this should give you the ruby path then select that form RubyMine

Comment: If you are using rvm RubyMine detects all the ruby automatically mostly.

Comment: Which ruby gives /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby. However I'm not able to select this path in Rubymine since the folder .rvm is hidden.

Comment: It solved by itself however I didn't do anything except typing some commands.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13688/discussion-between-priteshj-and-alex-maslakov)

Answer (score 2):

For posterity: don't select a Ruby version from the wrappers folders that are generated by rvm. Ruby thinks it's OK, but you get the Rails error.

Answer (score 1):

When gem installed locally, just add the path to the SDK:

for example: `~/.gem/ruby/2.2.0/gems` on `File` > `Project Settings` > `Platform Settings` > `SDKs` > `Classpath` (press `+` button)

Answer (score 0):

When you close and open again you will get a notification saying:

> RubyMine Gem Manager: RubyMine has detected that some of the gems required for 'projectName' are not installed. Install

Click `Install` and it will run the bundle install for the project, all got solved after that.