# Unable to run cucumber test on intellij idea 12

Tags: ruby, macos, intellij-idea, rubygems, cucumber

I have followed all necessary steps an installed ruby and bundle.

```
which ruby
/Users/v-bpurkayastha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby

which gem
/Users/v-bpurkayastha/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/gem
```

but on `intellij` idea while running it say

```
 Cucumber support disabled because 'cucumber-rails' gem or Cucumber Rails plugin 
 are missing. Install gem and add it to the Gemfile
```

On run configuration it says

```
No cucumber gem found in sdk
```

even after selecting sdk.

Please help me out.
many thanks,

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11418569/2650174) for RubyMine but it will helpful for you issue.

Comment: Can any tell what is 'Gems bin directory intellij'

Answer (score 4):

I have had a similar issue with my **IntelliJ Idea 14** where it was incorrectly assigning the path for **Gems bin directory** under project settings' SDK for Ruby.

I changed it to /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/bin and when running the cucumber tests it picks it up and run the acceptance tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I viewed the module settings it did show the cucumber gem in the list. I clicked on the cucumber gem and clicked 'update gems'. It did find a newer version of the cucumber gem (1.3.15 instead of 1.3.14) and updated it. I was able to run my cucumber tests after that with no error.

Answer (score 0):

For my version (IntelliJ 2018.3 Ultimate), since my project is consisted of java modules as well as cucumber test module (in the "test/func" folder). I had to

1. Set up ruby and its gem
2. Import the test folder as a module

   - Project Setting -> Modules, add a module by import existing source
3. Add the Ruby SDK to that module