# Unable to run gem rails. Cannot find 'rails' rubymine error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I get this problem whenever I want to start a new rails project in RubyMine. This issue has been sorted before here but the solution makes absolute no sense to me thus still stranded. Would love it in detailed simple words.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418408/rubymine-rails-gem-not-found) is pretty simple and clear. You just need to find where your Ruby installation is and tell Rubymine that that's where it needs to look for `ruby`, `rails`, etc. Your gems might be in a different spot and you'd have to tell Rubymine that as well.

Comment: You say you found a solution here that didn't make sense to you, but you didn't say which one you found.  There is an exemplar that I'm going to mark this question a duplicate of.  Hopefully that question helps you.  If the exemplar is the solution that didn't make sense to you, then please ask a new question explaining in detail what you don't understand about it.

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK and Gems

Then choose the version of ruby you want to run your project in, preferably the one that already has rails installed. If you choose one that doesn't, simply do `gem install rails` then `bundle install` for that version in the terminal.