# Cucumber support disabled because 'cucumber-rails' gem or Cucumber Rails plugin are missing

Tags: cucumber, rubymine, rbenv

The solution from similar question does not work for me.
My setup:
[image]

I'm trying to make it working rbenv + cucumber but whenever i try to run specific feature file from the IDE i get the error "Cucumber support disabled because 'cucumber-rails' gem or Cucumber Rails plugin are missing. Install gem and add it to the Gemfile."
The gem seems like its present.

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11418408/rubymine-rails-gem-not-found/11418569#11418569) answer but issue still persists.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

cucumber != cucumber-rails

Adding cucumber-rails to Gemfile or installing it manually gem install cucumber-rails fixes the problem